# Как в WPF просмотреть изображение?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется объект `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. В WinForms можно было просто использовать `PictureBox`, чтобы просмотреть изображение. В WPF есть контрол `Image`, которому `Bitmap` скормить нельзя. Нашел способ переделки в `BitmapImage`

```
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                ms.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
                return bi;
            }

    ImageBox.Source = logic.NextPage(); // это объект Image
```

Но ничего не происходит (хотя и ошибок нет). Нужна помощь.

Comment: А откуда у вас в WPF взялся System.Drawing.Bitmap? Это класс из Windows Forms. В WPF используйте System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.

Comment: Кстати, да. Проще всего вообще не работать с `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

Comment: @VladD я знаю, что это класс из WinForms. Однако ничего поделать тут не могу - работаю со сторонней сборкой.

Comment: @RussCoder: Понятно. Сейчас поищу, где-то у меня вроде был код.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
```

перед

```
bi.StreamSource = ms;
```

Пояснение: `BitmapImage` содержит внутри оптимизацию, которая не грузит данные сразу, а запоминает `StreamSource` и грузит потом. Но вы уничтожаете `MemoryStream` (что правильно), поэтому `BitmapImage` не может позже загрузит данные.

---

Для будущих поколений:

```
System.Windows.Media.ImageSource BitmapToImageSource(System.Windows.Bitmap bmp)
{
    using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        img.BeginInit();
        img.CacheOption = System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        img.StreamSource = ms;
        img.EndInit();
        return img;
    }
}
```